# Trouble Implementing 1d Wave Equation Finite Difference Solver

Tags: pde, finite-difference, algorithms, numerics

Im trying to solve the 1d Wave Equation on $x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0$: $$u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}, \hspace{5mm} u(x,0) = \cos(4 \pi x), \hspace{5mm} u_t(x,0) = 0$$ with $c = 1$ and a periodic boundary condition $$u(x,t) = u(x+1,t)$$ Im using central difference in time and space:

$$\frac{u_j^{n+1} - 2u_j^n + u_j^{n-1}}{k^2} = c^2 \frac{u_{j+1}^n - 2u_j^n + u_{j-1}^n}{h^2}$$ and the notation $r = c\frac{k}{h}$ which gives the iteration $$u_{j}^{n+1} = 2u_j^n - u_j^{n-1} + r^2(u_{j+1}^n - 2u_j^n + u_{j-1}^n)$$ And then for $n = 0$, to find $u_j^{n-1}$ I use the Neumann condition $$u_t(x,0) = \frac{u_j^{1} - u_j^{-1}}{2k} = 0
$$ which gives $u_j^{-1} = u_j^1$. Inserting this into the original discretisation then gives for $n = 0$ $$u_j^1 = u_j^0 + \frac{1}{2}r^2(u_{j+1}^0  - 2u_j^0 + u_{j-1}^0)$$ Below is my implementation in Python:

```
class wave_eq:
    def __init__(self,init_m,init_n):


        self.M = init_m
        self.N = init_n

        self.x_grid = [np.linspace(0, 1,self.M + 2)]
        self.t_grid = np.linspace(0, 1, self.N + 2)


        self.solution = []


    def forward_euler_solver(self,g):
        M = self.M
        N = self.N 


        h = self.x_grid[1] - self.x_grid[0]

        k = self.t_grid[1] - self.t_grid[0]

        r = k/h
        u = np.zeros(shape = (M+2,N+1))

        u[:,0] = g(self.x_grid) #apply initial condition u(x,0) = g(x)


        for i in range(N+1):
            new_u  = np.zeros(shape = (M+2,N+1))
            for j in range(M+1):

                if (i == 0): #using Neumann condition at first time step
                    new_u[j][i] = u[j][i] + ((r**2)/2)*(u[j+1][i] - 2*u[j][i] + u[j-1][I]) 
                else:
                    new_u[j][i] = 2*u[j][i] - u[j][i-1] + (r**2)*(u[j+1][i] -2*u[j][i] + u[j-1][i])

            new_u[-1][i] = new_u[0][i] #Apply periodic boundary condition


            u = new_u
          
        self.solution.append(u)


def init_c_g(x):
    return np.cos(4*np.pi*x)
```

The relative $\ell_2$ error is very small, and comes out as $7 \cdot 10^{-7}$ but the solution does not converge and in fact grows slightly when adding more points in the $x$-space, as can be seen from the figure below where I plotted the relative $\ell_2$ error versus number of points in the $x$-space.

[image]

The analytical solution I used as reference to compute the plot is $$\frac{1}{2} \big (\cos(4 \pi (x-t) + \cos(4 \pi (x+t)) \big) $$I belive there is only a small error somewhere (perhaps when applying the boundary condition?) but I can't seem to figure it out. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I believe your application of the perdiodic BC is wrong. You should not enforce the values of the solution itself. What you need to do is compute $\partial_{xx} u$  at all inner nodes (not the outer ones) first, using your standard centered-scheme. Then handle the outer nodes separately: for instance at point $x=0$, you conceptually introduce a "ghost point" at $x=-dx$, set its value to u[-1] (i.e. it will mimic the opposite boundary node), and apply your scheme: `dudxx[0] = (u[1] - 2*u[0] + u[-1])/dx**2`. Do a similar thing on the opposite side and that should work.

Comment: btw, you should avoid using for loops in Python, and instead vectorize your code. There a lot of examples online on how to do that ;)

Comment: @Laurent90 How could I solve for the ghost point at $x = -dx$? Since when solving for $u[0]$ I have not yet found $u[-1]$. Im new to finite differences so the method is still somewhat confusing to me.

Comment: just like when solving the heat equation I think: your vector $u$ has the values of the discrete solution at all nodes (i.e. u[0]and u[-1] are part of your solution and do not need to be solved for). The RHS at $c^2 \partial_{xx} u$ can be evaluated in a straightforward manner for the nodes 1 to N-2 as you've done. The "trick"  to compute this RHS for the first point (and can be done for the alst one in a similar fashion) is to introduce an additional point befort that first point, i.e. ass if you had extended the domain by $dx$ to its left, and to use it as I have written before.

Comment: The value of $u$ at this point can be determined easily: for a Neumann condition ($\partial_x u=0$ at the boudnary), the discrete equation would be $\dfrac{u(t, x=0)-u_{left~ghost}(t)}{dx}=0$ therefore $u_{left~ghost} (t)=u(t, x=0)$.
For a perdiodic BC, you set $u_{left~ghost} (t) = $u(x=L,t)$, thus it is as if you were connecting the first and last points by "folding" your mesh. The same sort of question arise for the discrete heat equation, so maybe you can find more examples there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am by no means experienced with the wave equation, but I think the issue comes from the imposition of the periodic BCs.

The periodic boundary conditions can be imposed by using ghost points: you do as if you were considering an extended system which, in Python terms, would have the state vector:

```
u_extend=[u[-1], u[0], u[1], ..., u[M-1], u[M], u[0]]
```

The bold values are duplicated values from the outer points of the original values. They allow to apply the laplacian operator easily at the boundaries.

*Remark:* For a Neumann BC $\partial_x u(x=0,t)=\partial_x u(x=L,t) = 0$, the ghost points would instead be (at first-order):

```
u_extend=[u[0], u[0], u[1], ..., u[M-1], u[M], u[M]]
```

This is actually the reason why your code does have M+2 space points, and not just M. Points 1 and M+2 (so 0 and M+1 in Python indices) are meant to be your ghost points. However you were not handling them correctly, you were only setting the value of the ghost point at point M+2, not the ghost point at point 0. Also I am quite confused with your usage of `new_u` which I think is not correct, as you basically replace your whole solution history with zeros, apart from the last step...

Here is a revision of your code, with comments to describe my corrections:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class wave_eq:
    def __init__(self,init_m,init_n):
        self.M = init_m
        self.N = init_n

        # self.x_grid = np.linspace(0, 1,self.M + 2) # no need for [ ... ]
        # I think this space grid introduces a small error in the placement of
        # the outer nodes with respect to the imposition of the boundary condition
        # better to use:
        self.x_grid = np.linspace(0,1,self.M)
        # AND then add the ghost point location
        dx = self.x_grid[1]-self.x_grid[0]
        self.x_grid = np.hstack((-dx, self.x_grid, self.x_grid[-1]+dx ))
        # then your "true" points really go from x=0 to x=1
        
        self.t_grid = np.linspace(0, 1, self.N + 2)
        self.solution = []


    def forward_euler_solver(self,g):
        M = self.M
        N = self.N 

        h = self.x_grid[1] - self.x_grid[0]
        k = self.t_grid[1] - self.t_grid[0]

        r = k/h
        u = np.zeros(shape = (M+2,N+2)) # initial time + (N+1) forward steps

        u[:,0] = g(self.x_grid) #apply initial condition u(x,0) = g(x)

        print(N,M,len(self.t_grid))
        for i in range(N+1):
            print('time step {}/{}'.format(i+1,N+1))
            # for j in range(M+1): # better if vectorised
            if (i == 0): #using Neumann condition at first time step
                # new_u[j][i] = u[j][i]   + ((r**2)/2)*(u[j+1][i] - 2*u[j][i]   + u[j-1][I]) 
                u[1:-1,i+1]   = u[1:-1,i] +  (r**2)   *(u[2:,i]   - 2*u[1:-1,i] + u[:-2,i])
                # --> r**2, not (r*2)/2
                # --> i, not I
            else:
                # new_u[j][i] = 2*u[j][i]   - u[j][i-1]   + (r**2)*(u[j+1][i] - 2*u[j][i]   + u[j-1][i])
                u[1:-1,i+1]   = 2*u[1:-1,i] - u[1:-1,i-1] + (r**2)*(u[2:,i]   - 2*u[1:-1,i] + u[:-2,i])
                
            #new_u[-1][i] = new_u[0][i] #Apply periodic boundary condition
            #Apply periodic boundary condition by using the ghost points
            u[ 0,i+1]  = u[-3,i+1] # on the left side
            u[-1,i+1]  = u[ 2,i+1]  # on the right side

            # u[ 0,i+1]  = u[-2,i+1] would be incorrect !
            # u[ 0,i+1]  = u[ 1,i+1] would be incorrect !
          
        self.solution = u


def init_c_g(x):
    return np.cos(4*np.pi*x)

    
def analytical_sol(t,x):
    # only for c=1
    return 0.5 *( np.cos(4*np.pi*(x-t)) + np.cos(4*np.pi*(x+t)) )

obj = wave_eq(init_m=100, init_n=1000)
obj.forward_euler_solver(g=init_c_g)

#%%
nt = obj.solution.shape[1]
ylim = [np.min(obj.solution), np.max(obj.solution)]

for i in range(1,nt,200): # plot every several time step
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(obj.x_grid, obj.solution[:,i])
    plt.plot(obj.x_grid, analytical_sol(obj.t_grid[i], obj.x_grid))
    plt.ylim(ylim)
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
    plt.ylabel(r'$u$')
```

Also on a side note, for you convergence analysis, I assume you have a fixed time step value that does not change when the number of mesh points is increased. That may cause the error of the time discretisation to dominate the overall error for highly refined grids. Just in case, the convergence analysis is performed in the last part of the code snippet.

***How to improve the error***

There are two sources of error: the space discretisation (the discrete laplacian you use is second-order accurate), and the temporal scheme (here only first-order accurate). So your error (at one point in space) is $\epsilon= O(\Delta t) + O(\Delta x^2) = O(1/N) + O(1/M^2)$.
You can improve the error at least in two ways:

- take smaller space and time steps
- use higher-order schemes, both in space and time.

My initial answer with adaptive time stepping ensures that the error coming from the time discretisation is both high-order and very low, thus you get $\epsilon \approx O(\Delta x^2)$, i.e. you only see the error of your spatial scheme. You could try using high-order finite differences (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient#Central_finite_difference for coefficients), however they will require adding additional ghost points, because the spatial scheme's stencil will extend.

I've complemented my own code with a generic laplacian soatial scheme with orders 2, 4 or 6 (coefficients taken from the previous wiki page). They work very well, and actually led me to realise that there is **another issue with the ghost points used** here: points 0 and points N are actually duplicates, i.e. they are supposed to be identical at all times if periodic conditions are used. Therefore, the left ghost point should not be `u[-1]` but `u[-2]` for example. Doing so has greatly improved the convergence, as well as made the adaptive integration much quicker, as the laplacian was previously not smooth at the boundaries. Otherwise you could just drop your last mesh point.

The following figure shows your mesh (in thick blue), and the "ghost" meshes used for the periodicity. It is clear that `u[0]=u[-1]` at all times, and that the correct ghost points are `u[-2]` (left) and `u[1]` (right).

[image: mesh and "ghost" meshes]

***Appendix***

Here is my first answer for completeness, with a code I wrote to solve this problem. I reformulated the 2nd-order system ODE as a system of 1st-order ODE by introducing $v = \partial_t u$ as additional field. I use a standard high-order adaptive ODE solver (from Scipy) to solve the semi-discrete system (after discretisation in space), so that the error from the time discretisation is negligible.

```py
"""
The ODE d_{tt} u = c^2 d_{xx} u is trasnformed to a first-order ODE by introducing
v = du/dt: 
            d/dt (u, v) = (v, c^2 d_{xx} u)
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate

#%% define the problem
N = 1000 # number of mesh points
mesh = np.linspace(0,1,N) # spatial mesh
dx = mesh[1]-mesh[0] # spatial step size
c = 1. # wave speed
tf = 1. # final time
order=6 # order of the spatial scheme

# initial condition
u0 = np.cos(4*np.pi*mesh)
du0dt = 0.*u0 # initially at rest
y0 = np.vstack((u0,du0dt)).reshape((-1,), order='F') # initial solution for the first order ODE system

#%% Solve as a 1st-order ODE
coeffs = ((1,-2,1),
          (-1/12,4/3,-5/2,4/3,-1/12),
          (1/90,-3/20,3/2,-49/18,3/2,-3/20,1/90))
orders = (2,4,6)

def computeLaplacian(u,order):
    """ Finite-difference Laplacian with periodic BCs"""
    iord = orders.index(order)
    coef = coeffs[iord]
    stencil_halfwidth = int((len(coef)-1)/2) # number of required neighbours to one side
    N = u.size
    
    # create state vector with ghost points (ghosts_left, u, ghost_right)
    u_extended = np.zeros((N+2*stencil_halfwidth,))
    u_extended[stencil_halfwidth:-stencil_halfwidth] = u[:]
    # u_extended[0:stencil_halfwidth]  = u[-stencil_halfwidth:]
    # u_extended[N+stencil_halfwidth:] = u[:stencil_halfwidth]
    # In fact, I had to correct this, because the endpoints are actually physical duplicates...
    u_extended[0:stencil_halfwidth]  = u[-stencil_halfwidth-1:-1]
    u_extended[N+stencil_halfwidth:] = u[1:stencil_halfwidth+1]
    
    # compute laplacian
    laplacian = np.zeros_like(u)
    for i in range(len(coef)):
        laplacian[:] = laplacian[:] + coef[i]*u_extended[i:N+i]
    return laplacian

def laplacienOrder2(u):
    """ The original spatial scheme """
    laplacian = np.zeros_like(u)
    laplacian[1:-1] = (u[:-2] - 2*u[1:-1] + u[2:])
    #  - periodic BCs
    u_ghost_left  = u[-1]
    u_ghost_right = u[0]
    laplacian[0] = (u_ghost_left - 2*u[0] + u[1])
    laplacian[-1] = (u_ghost_right - 2*u[-1] + u[-2])
    return laplacian

def odefun(t,x, c, dx, order):
    """ first-order ODE for the wave equation c d_{tt} u = c^2 d_{xx} u """
    u, dudt = x[::2], x[1::2]    
    laplacian = computeLaplacian(u,order)
    ddudtt = ((c/dx)**2)*laplacian
    return np.vstack((dudt,ddudtt)).reshape((-1,), order='F')

def analytical_sol(t,x):
    return 0.5 *( np.cos(4*np.pi*(x-t)) + np.cos(4*np.pi*(x+t)) )

#%% observe the evolution of the solution     
sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun=odefun, t_span=(0,tf), t_eval=np.linspace(0,tf,30),
                                y0=y0, method='DOP853', rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10,
                                args=(c,dx,order))
nt = sol.t.size
u, v = sol.y[::2,:], sol.y[1::2,:]
for i in range(nt): #0,nt,max([1,int(nt/20)]) ):    
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(mesh, u[:,i], label='numerical')
    plt.plot(mesh, analytical_sol(sol.t[i], mesh), linestyle='--', label='analytical')
    plt.ylim(np.min(u),np.max(u))
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend(loc='upper right', framealpha=0)
    plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
    plt.ylabel(r'$u$')
    plt.title('t={:.2f}'.format(sol.t[i]))
                
#%% Convergence analysis
tf = 0.5
Nvec = np.unique(np.logspace(1,np.log10(2000),10).astype(int))
meshes, sols = [], []
for i,N in enumerate(Nvec):
    print('{}/{} (N={})'.format(i+1,len(Nvec),N))
    mesh = np.linspace(0,1,N) # spatial mesh
    dx = mesh[1]-mesh[0] # spatial step size
    
    # initial condition
    u0 = np.cos(4*np.pi*mesh)
    du0dt = 0.*u0 # initially at rest
    y0 = np.vstack((u0,du0dt)).reshape((-1,), order='F') # initial solution for the first order ODE system

    if 1: # adaptive solving with tight tolerances
        sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun=odefun, t_span=(0,tf), t_eval=np.linspace(0,tf,2),
                                    y0=y0, method='DOP853', rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-13,
                                    args=(c,dx,order))
    else: #hack to get constant time steps with solve_ivp (only for explicit schemes)
        dt = 1e-3
        sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun=odefun, t_span=(0,tf), t_eval=np.linspace(0,tf,2),
                                  y0=y0, method='DOP853', rtol=1e99, atol=1e99,
                                  max_step=dt, first_step=dt, args=(c,dx,order))
    sols.append( sol )
    meshes.append(mesh)
    

#%% Error analysis
error_analytical = np.zeros(( Nvec.size )) # error relative to analytical solution
error_analytical_point = np.zeros(( Nvec.size )) # error relative to analytical solution
error_finest_point = np.zeros(( Nvec.size )) # error relative to the finest numerical solution
for i in range(len(Nvec)):
    error_analytical[i] = np.sqrt( np.sum( (sols[i].y[::2,-1] - analytical_sol(tf, meshes[i]))**2 )/ meshes[i].size )
    error_analytical_point[i] = np.abs(sols[i].y[0,-1] - analytical_sol(tf, 0.))
    error_finest_point[i] = np.abs(sols[i].y[0,-1] - sols[-1].y[0,-1])
    
plt.figure()
dx = (1/Nvec)
plt.loglog(dx, error_analytical, marker='o', label='vs analytical (2-norm)')
plt.loglog(dx, error_analytical_point, marker='o', label='vs analytical (BC point)')
plt.loglog(dx[:-1], error_finest_point[:-1], marker='o', label='vs finest (BC point)')
iref = 0 #int(len(Nvec)/2) # used to plot reference convergence orders
plt.loglog(dx, error_analytical[iref]*(dx/dx[iref])**(order), label='order {}'.format(order), linestyle='--', color='r')
plt.loglog(dx, error_analytical[iref]*(dx/dx[iref])**(2*order), label='order {}'.format(2*order), linestyle='--', color='b')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('dx')
plt.ylabel('error')
plt.ylim(1e-16, 1e-2)
```

Here are the numerical and analytical solutions after 1 seconds (1000 mesh points):
[image: solution at 1s]

And here is the convergence result for the 6-th order scheme:

[image]

Here, the 6-th order spatial scheme converges with order 12, and (4th-order reaches order 8, 2nd-order reaches order 4...) I am not sure if I missed something, but that is strange !

As I said, I am not experienced with this kind of problem, so I am open to remarks and suggestions !

Comment: Your solution is very nice and efficient, but do you see if there is a simple way I could incorporate the periodic bcs correctly in my function? That way it would be easier to expand the function later since I understand it fully. I understand what you said about "folding" the mesh, but still struggle with understanding how to find the ghost points since we have no Neumann condition in the x-direction therefore I don't see how to compute the first and last points for each time. Also, Im wondering what the  $t$ and $x$ parameters are in your odefun function?

Comment: I'll try and take a closer look at your, but so far I had trouble understanding your for loops. Regarding `odefun`, the argument `t`is the time of evaluation of the RHS, and `x` is the corresponding state vector: $x=(u_0, v_0, u_1, v_1, ... , u_N, v_n)^t$ where $v_i=d_t u_i$.

Comment: Preferably I would like to solve the problem without doing temporal integration with built-in functions if possible.

Comment: Saw your edit now, the function works very nicely :) Thank you so much for the help! :) Is there a way to get the numerical approximation to get arbitrarily close to the analytical solution with this method? Im able to get the relative l2 error to be about $10^{-5}$ with this method depending on how I choose number of time steps and number of steps in $x$-direction. The convergence is of second order like expected.

Comment: I have added more info on higher-order schemes and updated my code.

Comment: The higher order schemes are definitely interesting, 12th order convergence is quite impressive. Would it be difficult to extend this into 2d? i.e solving $$u_{tt} = c^2(u_{xx} + u_{yy}).$$ Would be interesting to see if the convergence rates are the same or if they change when adding one more dimension.

Comment: Yes, the schemes should be easy to implement in 2D. The 12th-order convergence sems weird, I think I must have missed something in my code or in the theory, but the solution is indeed very accurate.

Comment: One thing I didn't understand is that you set u[ 0,i+1]  = u[-2,i+1] and u[-1,i+1]  = u[ 1,i+1] I Thought this was only true if you have a Neumann condition in the x-direction? From the periodic BC I thought we only knew u[-1]= u[0] since the first and last points are the same.

Comment: Let's take the 2nd-order scheme as an example. At a given point space point $x$ in the mesh, $d_{xx} u$ is approximated bu $(u(x-dx) - 2u(x) + u(x+dx))/dx^2$. We know that the positions $x$ and $x+1$ are identical, due to the periodicity. Thus, for $x=0$, $dx^2 d_{xx}u(0)=u(0-dx)-2u(0)+u(dx)=u(1-dx)-2u(0)+u(dx)$ by simply using the periodicity of $u$. You can experiment with my laplacian function by uncommenting the first lines, and looking at the reconstructed laplacian versus the analytical one. You will see that, without this fix, the laplacian is discontinuous at the interface.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: When using ghost points, we know that the value at $x = -dx$ is equal to the value at u[-1] = u[0] due to periodicity (imagining that we are "folding" the mesh). Then due to periodicity again we know that the value at $x = -dx$ equals the value at $x = -dx +1 = u[-2]$ therefore $u[0] = u[-2]$ and for the other side the idea is the same.

Comment: I've added a figure to explain this in my answer. If you have more questions, please go to the chat instead: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121101/discussion-between-laurent90-and-pame